# Django decimal precision loss

Tags: python, django, precision

```
worth = Decimal(request.POST.get('worth'))
print(request.user.profile.cash) # -> prints 10000.000000000000000
print(worth) # -> prints 10000
Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).update(cash=F('cash')-worth)
request.user.profile.refresh_from_db()
if request.user.profile.cash < 0:
     ###!!!!####
     print(request.user.profile.cash) # -> -1.819E-12

#model definition:
class Profile(models.Model):
    cash = models.DecimalField(default=10000, max_digits=30, decimal_places=15)
```

as can be seen, the player has 10k cash and I subtract 10k, which results in minus values, how can I solve this problem? I don't allow cash to be negative as you can expect. Am I doing something principally wrong?

I want the player to be able to go all-in with his money.

Comment: What is `user.profile.cash`  ?

Comment: Maybe `F()` expression implicitly convert the decimal to a floating point number? The value `-1.1819E-12` is a floating point number.

Comment: Which database backend are you using? This might be a db-specific issue. For example, SQLlite doesn't have a native decimal field. Django has to use some workaround there.

Comment: @HåkenLid very nice point of you, I'm using SQLite, that sounds like the reason. David's answer also points out the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to fix this by doing the subtraction of the worth from the cash in python (i.e. not with a database query).  I'm pretty sure you'd have to convert worth to a `Decimal` value first in order to do this.  The reason this might work is that Django uses `Decimal` values from the `decimal` module to do arithmetic with decimal field values which have perfect precision for decimal numbers.  I'm not sure what your database is doing when you make that query, but it must involve some kind of floating point math.  The value you're seeing is basically equivalent to zero (-0.000000000001819) but with some floating point error included.